# How to access SensorTag Data on Beagle Bone Black?

Tags: ibm-cloud, beagleboneblack, watson-iot

After following the link below, I have been able to connect a sensortag to a beaglebone black and then have the beaglebone relay the sensor data, collected by the sensortag, to the IBM Watson IoT Platform. In the Watson platform I can visualize the data from all 10 different sensors. Is it possible to access the raw data collection on the beagle bone before it is sent to Watson? I want to possibly run data processing on the beaglebone before sending it to the Watson. If you have any experience working with a sensortag and the beagle bone black, your advice would be much appreciated. Thank you.

https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/connecting-a-beaglebone-with-sensortag-to-the-iot-foundation/

Comment: You might consider also asking your question at the bottom of the referenced recipe.

Answer (score 0):

It was long ago I worked with Ti Sensor tag & BBB. You have to use [Bluez](http://www.bluez.org/) libraries as [GATT Client](https://github.com/gbrault/gattclient) and use it fetch the data from BLE Sensor Tag. The sensor tag GATT Server attribute table is given in this [PDF](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/images/a/a8/BLE_SensorTag_GATT_Server.pdf).